# How to make factory_girl transient work with association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Previously I had a factory looking like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :file do
    ignore do
      attachment_id 1
    end

    trait :file_with_autoplay do
      type_key "file_with_autoplay"
      attrs {{
        "path" => attachment_id,
        "volume" => 1
      }}
    end
  end
end
```

And when I built the factory using

```
create(:file, :file_with_autoplay, { story: story, attachment_id: attachment.id } )
```

and it worked fine.

Now I had to refactor models a little bit. Before `Story` had `File` with columns `type_key` and `attrs`. Now `File` has one-to-one model `Config`, where I extracted `type_key` and `attrs`

So, my factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :file do
    ignore do
      attachment_id nil
    end

    trait :file_with_autoplay do
      association :config,
        configuration_type: "file",
        type_key: "file_with_autoplay",
        attrs: {
          "path" => "#{attachment_id}",
          "volume" => 1
        }
    end
  end
end
```

So, not much changed, but I am passing attachment_id now to association. 
When I run the tests, I get

```
ArgumentError:
   Trait not registered: attachment_id
```

For clarity this is my new `config` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :config do
    ignore do
      attachment_id nil
    end
    configuration_type "file"
    type_key "file_with_autoplay"
    attrs {{
      "generic_attr" => "generic_value"
    }}
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong here? How should I pass attachment_id transient through association in Factory Girl?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, then I see no error. Test fails though, because I validate if path exists.

Comment: with curly braces there is syntax error. With just `"path => attachment_id.to_s,` still `Trait not registered: attachment_id`

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106025/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-qnsi).